# Time spent to sort 10^7 records with insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, insertion-sort

I am stuck with my revision for the upcoming test.

The question says:

> An implementation of insertion sort spent 1 second to sort a list of 10^6 records. How many seconds it will spend to sort 10^7 records?

By using

```
T(X)/T(1) = 10^7/10^6
```

I thought the answer was 10 seconds but the actual answer says it's 100 seconds.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: If your calculation were true, insertion sort would be the best sorting algorithm :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer would have been correct if insertion sort were an operation that ran in *linear* (i.e. `O(n)`) time. But it's not.

Insertion sort has an average-case complexity of `O(n^2)` (i.e. it's quadratic). Loosely, that means that it will on average take 4 times as long to sort 2 times as many records; 9 times as long to sort 3 times as many; 16 times as long to sort 4 times as many; and so forth.

The question asks you how long it would take to sort 10 times as many records; what's 10 squared times 1 second?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the performance of an [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), it's defined as О(n^2) - this means that when n is increased by a factor of 10, the time it takes would increase by a factor of n^2 (100)

Answer (score 1):

As we know that Insertion Sort is an O(n^2) algorithm lets assume that T(n) is its time complexity.
So **T(n)=c*n^2***                                                                                        for some constant c>0
we are given that T(10^6)=1. So **c(10^6)*(10^6)=1***.We get the value of c as 10^-12.Plugging this value of c in **T(10^7)=c(10^7)*(10^7)*** implying **T(10^7)=(10^-12)(10^14)=100**.

Answer (score 0):

It's given that the insertion sort took 1 second to sort a particular list of 1 million numbers.

On average, insertion sort does approximately n(n-1)/4 comparisons and memory swaps. For n = 1e6, then this is 2.5e11, which even if every loop of the implementation could execute in 1 cycle (which is obviously unreasonable), the CPU would have to be running at 250GHz which is faster than any real CPU.

So it must have been that the original input list was mostly sorted already, and no conclusions can be drawn about the run-time on the second list.

Comment: I don't think that is within the spirit of the question.. however you are correct, the numbers seem unreasonable. That said, perhaps it's an improved [diamond-based CPU](http://www.geek.com/chips/81ghz-diamond-semiconductor-created-551147/)